# Automatic HTTPS on Openshift/AWS/some PaaS

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, openshift, gunicorn

I'm working on a Python project that depends on a package that runs Gunicorn as a web server. I need to support https, but the Gunicorn configuration exposed by the package doesn't allow me to pass in keyfile or certfile options, and 'http' is hard-coded throughout the package.

I was wondering if there's some easy way to get https working transparently between clients and Gunicorn without Gunicorn knowing about it, on OpenShift or any popular PaaS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenShift Online apparently handles this automatically by default.

Just change the http to https in the application url they give you (https://xxx-yyy.rhcloud.com) and you've got TLS using their *.rhcloud.com certificate.

I was expecting more configuration and just needed somebody to tell me "just change the url to https".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the solution purposed this Openshift KB https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1044-how-to-redirect-traffic-to-https

Comment: That's helpful, thanks! However, it's not clear to me where I'm supposed to be placing the .htaccess file. Does this excerpt from the link you've included apply to OpenShift Online?
"Applications of all language types except for JBoss and NodeJS uses Apache. So for these Apache-based applications, you can add a .htaccess file in your web root that looks like this:"